# transition or animation between display:not and display:block

Tags: javascript, animation, transition

how to i add an transition or animation to the navbar when im clicking on the menu button?

```
enter code here
```

https://codepen.io/ZTOX/pen/vWyRYz

Comment: Please post your code here - the question needs to be self-contained and self-explanatory.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Answer (score 0):

your codepen works fine, I see a transition. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i want it to like slide down and slower so you can see it i also want to know how i can add an animation when i have clicked the menu button. sorry for bad english and explonation.

Comment: hey, I have just used the following, and I think this is what you're looking for (plug it in anywhere you want with various values for seconds, obvioiusly): `.change .bar1{
    transform: rotate(-45deg)translate(-9px, 6px);
  transition-duration: .5s;
}`